# Can someone please explain this Objective-C syntax?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble making sense of the following:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
```

I understand that `UILabel` is a class. So we're creating a pointer named `*label` that points to an instance of `UILabel`.

Right of the equals sign, I understand that `[cell viewWithTag:1000];` is passing `cell` a method named `viewWithTag` with the argument `1000`.

What does the `(UILabel *)` before that mean?

Comment: It isn't passing a method; it's sending a message. Passing a method is a different and quite specific idea.

Comment: Sorry, coming from other OO languages and still getting my head around the terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means to cast the object type to a `UILabel*`.  By default, `viewWithTag:` returns a `UIView*`

Answer (score 1):

It is casting the result to a `UILabel`. The syntax is the same as in C - (Objective-C is a super-set of C).

You can also check the type before using it (although not really necessary if you are confident of what is being returned) using `isKindOfClass`